# Visualizar pdf em outra aba do navegador com php

Tags: php, javascript

Boa Tarde pessoal,

Seguinte, criei um formulário de orçamento em php e solicito que o usuário ao visitar meu site, possa solicitar o orçamento e enviar para minha base de dados. Então gostaria que, assim que ele clicar em enviar(Lembrando que ao enviar já faço o redirecionamento para outra página em java script) eu já consigo abrir em uma nova guia do navegador um orçamento geral em formato pdf que já vai estar em uma das minhas pastas no site. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize este código, que irá abrir no próprio navegador o arquivo. De preferência utilize o Google Chrome.

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=nome.pdf");
@readfile('files/nome.pdf');
```